# Calendar is not working for a custom profile in lightning

Tags: permissions, calendar, custom-profile

I have one custom profile and logged in with its user in a sandbox. I am accessing calendar tab in my app. it is giving me error while loading the object.

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. Error ID: 899128544-86421 (1358493370)

Does anyone know what I am missing? I don't have permission to "View setup and configuration". Although if I give this permission the error will be gone. but I can't as per the requirement.

Somewhere I got to know while searching for the solution that I should have "All-Day Event" field permission and I have it already.

is there any other workaround I can do?